# Se crea un bucle cuando no debería

Tags: c++, bucles

Este código debería de imprimir `Hello world!` siempre que el usuario diga que si, si el usuario dice que no, debería de acabar el programa, y si introduce un valor diferente, volver a preguntar.

El errror consiste en que si introduces "si" o "no", vuelve a preguntar, y si introduces otra cosa, finaliza.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char mas[2];
    bool valido = false;
    bool anhadir;
    if(anhadir == true){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    do{
        cout << "Quieres añadir más hábitos? (si o no)" << endl;
        cin >> mas;
        strcpy(mas, mas);
        if(mas == "si" || mas == "no"){
            valido = true;
        }
    }while(!valido);
    if(mas == "si"){
        anhadir = true;
    }else if(mas == "no"){
        anhadir = false;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char mas[2];` es demasiado corto para sostener `"si"` o `"no"`porque debe tener un terminador nulo, y que pasa si el usuario escribe algo más largo? Por favor utiliza `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, no corrijas la pregunta con las respuetas que recibes porque entonces las mismas dejan de tener sentido. Si te sigue dando problemas pon comentarios en las respuestas.

Las cadenas usan comillas dobles, no con comillas simples:

```
if(mas == "si" || mas == "no"){
```

Y lo mismo en las otras dos comparaciones que haces más adelante

Por otro lado, nota que las cadenas necesitan espacio para el caracter que finaliza la cadena, `\0`, es decir, para almacenar `"si"` o `"no"`, necesitas un array de, al menos, 3 caracteres:

```
char mas[3];
```

Por otro lado, las comparaciones de arrays no se hacen con el operador `==`, ya que este operador se limita a comparar las direcciones de memoria, que obviamente van a ser distintas. Para comparar arrays de caracteres hay que usar funciones tipo `strcmp`:

```
if( strcmp(mas, "si") == 0 )
    // ...
```

Sin embargo, no estás programando en C sino en C++, luego puedes usar clases propias de C++ para simplificarte un poco la vida:

```
std::string mas;
```

Ahora el operador `==` si va a funcionar como esperas ya que la clase `std::string` sobrecarga dicho operador, y esta sobrecarga lo que hace es comparar el contenido de las cadenas, no direcciones de memoria.

Una última cosa. Mucho cuidado con esta función:

```
strcpy(mas, mas);
```

Esta función es absurda ya que el origen y el destino son la misma cosa. Hay que tener cuidado con estas operaciones ya que hay bastantes casos en los que este tipo de operaciones te pueden dar problemas

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que la primera vez que contestes con "más" o "no" la variable bandera de pone a true. A partir de ese momento siempre vale true, con lo que nunca se cumplirá la salida del bucle. Para resolverlo, podrías poner una asignación a false antes del primer cout , o más comúnmente, asignar directamente el resultado de la comparación en la variable más. Es decir, cambia tu if por:

```
mas = strcmp("mas", mas) || strcmp("no", mas);
```

El resultado de esta operación será 1 o 0, que te vale como salida del bucle.